# How to solve for mixed copula weight coefficients using EM algorithm？

Tags: r, mixture, copula

In R language, I want to solve the weight coefficients of a multidimensional hybrid copula, it is better to be able to use different copula functions, or for a fixed copula function(clayton,gumbel,frank copula) if the conditions are restricted. Use EM algorithm or some other algorithm to calculate the weight coefficients. Thank you very much for your professional advice and guidance!

```
library(copula)
### Input three-dimension data :
x1 <- rnorm(n=1000,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.1)
x2 <- rlnorm(n = 1000,meanlog = 0.5,sdlog = 0.01)
x3 <- runif(n = 1000,min = 0.2,max = 0.8)
data<-matrix(c(x1,x2,x3),1000,3)
### mixture copula type:   clayton + gumbel + frank copula (or + normal copula \ t copula)
###for example:
copula1 <- mixCopula(list( claytonCopula  (param = 1.3,dim = 3),
                           frankCopula    (param = 2.718,dim = 3),
                           gumbelCopula   (param = 4.58,dim = 3)))
###EM algothrim.   
### output :  weight of mixture copula
```

Comment: Did you try mixture copula in Copula package?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76288252/computing-mixing-coefficients-weights-of-mixed-copula-model-gumbel-and-unstru/76420280#76420280

Comment: Yes，I've already built the mixture copula.  I have read your link before , but I see that your code is only used to build the mixed Gaussian model, how can I use it to calculate the weights of other mixture copula?  I look forward to your advice. Thanks !

Comment: Hi. Do you mean how we can replace gaussian copula with other copula such as Clayton and Frank? If yes, it is easy, just replace gaussian with any copula you want.

Comment: YES,  Just replace gaussian copula with other copula such as Clayton and Frank copula. But some difficulties bother me, see the reply below for details. I am eager to see your detailed insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To form a mixture copula model, you can use the 'Copula' package in R.

Here you go:

```
MixCop <- mixCopula(list(frankCopula(9,dim=3), claytonCopula(4, dim=3))) ## form the model
CopD <- rCopula(300, MixCop) ## generate the data 
Res <- fitCopula(CopD) ## estimate the model
```

##### based on your updated question:

```
library(copula)
### Input three-dimension data :
x1 <- rnorm(n=1000,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.1)
x2 <- rlnorm(n = 1000,meanlog = 0.5,sdlog = 0.01)
x3 <- runif(n = 1000,min = 0.2,max = 0.8)
data <- cbind(x1, x2,x3)
Copdat <- pobs(data)## transform the data to copula data 
### mixture copula type:   clayton + gumbel + frank copula (or + normal copula \ t copula)
###for example:
copula1 <- mixCopula(list( claytonCopula  (param = 1.3,dim = 3),
                           frankCopula    (param = 2.718,dim = 3),
                           gumbelCopula   (param = 4.58,dim = 3)))
cop <- fitCopula(copula1, Copdat)
```

### The result:

```
> cop <- fitCopula(copula1, Copdat)
Warning messages:
1: In .local(copula, tau, ...) :
  For the Gumbel copula, tau must be >= 0. Replacing negative values by 0.
2: In fitCopula.ml(copula, u = data, method = method, start = start,  :
  var.mpl(copula, u) failed: system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.5821e-29
> cop
Call: fitCopula(copula1, data = Copdat)
Fit based on "maximum pseudo-likelihood" and 1000 3-dimensional observations.
Copula: mixExplicitCopula 
 m1.alpha  m2.alpha  m3.alpha        w1        w2        w3 
3.893e+00 8.883e-01 1.000e+00 5.682e-14 1.060e-10 1.000e+00 
The maximized loglikelihood is -2.649e-06 
Optimization converged
```

#### I advise you to try other types of copula functions for your data.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are some errors in the answer to the last question (see the link you sent), you can try to run it. ERROR: "Error in cor(x) : Either set 'x' and 'y' at the same time, or set only matrix 'x'."

Comment: My question is: 
### Input three-dimension data :
x1 <- rnorm(n=1000,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.1)
x2 <- rlnorm(n = 1000,meanlog = 0.5,sdlog = 0.01)
x3 <- runif(n = 1000,min = 0.2,max = 0.8)
data<-matrix(c(x1,x2,x3),1000,3)
### mixture copula type:   clayton + gumbel + frank copula (or + normal copula \ t copula)
###for example:
copula1 <- mixCopula(list( claytonCopula  (param = 1.3,dim = 3),
                           frankCopula    (param = 2.718,dim = 3),
                           gumbelCopula   (param = 4.58,dim = 3)))
###EM algothrim.  ### then OUtput :  weight of mixture copula

Comment: Ok. So, you want to form three dimensions mixture copula model and estimate the mixture weight? I will edit my post.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your professional comments and I look forward to reading your posts.

Comment: You are more than welcome. Could you please update your question with your code?

Comment: OK, I have updated my question.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your updated question. I will look at my other reply (the link) later.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask what principle “fitcopula ”uses to calculate the weight coefficient? I use “help (fitcopula)” in R , but there is no explanation of the relevant content.

Comment: I have another small problem, please see if there is a good solution, thank you！[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77408523/how-to-estimate-copula-parameter-value-for-three-dimension-copula-function

Comment: fitcop is a function that estimates the model parameters, including the mixture weight. So, if you fit a non-mixture model, it will return the estimated parameters of the fitted model.

Comment: I posted my answer. Have a look.