# how to estimate copula parameter value for three-dimension copula function？

Tags: r, copula

Hello，in R language， i want to calculate copula parameter *θ* and the AIC value of the three-dimension copula function（not for vine copula）, is there a relevant package and function to calculate directly? as I know，for two-dimension copula(or for vine copula)，there are some functions like **BiCopEst()** and **RVineAIC（）**. However,when I fitCopula,how to calculate the AIC value of the three-dimension copula function is a question for me. could everybody help me?  Thanks!

```
### data 
x1 <- rnorm(1000,mean = 8,sd = 2)
x2 <- rnorm(1000,mean = 4,sd = 1)
x3 <- rnorm(1000,mean = 5,sd = 0.5)
u  <- matrix(c(x1,x2,x3),1000,3)
ux1 <- ecdf(x1)
ux1 <- ux1(x1)
ux2 <- ecdf(x2)
ux2 <- ux2(x2)
ux3 <- ecdf(x3)
ux3 <- ux3(x2)
data1<-matrix(c(ux1,ux2,ux3),1000,3)
###fit copula 
clay.cop <- fitCopula(claytonCopula(dim = 3), data1, method = "itau")
### then how to get AIC for this copula?
```

Comment: To find the AIC, just use its equations. -2*loglikelihood of the model + 2 p (where p is the number of the estimated parameters of the model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, based on your provided data.

```
x1 <- rnorm(1000,mean = 8,sd = 2)
x2 <- rnorm(1000,mean = 4,sd = 1)
x3 <- rnorm(1000,mean = 5,sd = 0.5)
Copdat <- pobs(cbind(x1,x2,x3))
###fit copula 
clay.cop <- fitCopula(claytonCopula(dim = 3),Copdat)
```

### Output

```
> clay.cop
Call: fitCopula(claytonCopula(dim = 3), data = Copdat)
Fit based on "maximum pseudo-likelihood" and 1000 3-dimensional observations.
Copula: claytonCopula 
  alpha 
0.02053 
The maximized loglikelihood is 0.5753 
Optimization converged
```

To calculate the AIC, use its equation directly, where the loglikelihood is the one given in the result, and the number of the parameters is the estimated parameter; for your case, it is only the parameter of the Clayton copula.

AIC = -2 loglikelihood + 2 p   ## p is the number of the estimated parameters of the model.

Comment: Hi, @Dr. Alenezi, I have another question, please help to see if there is a good idea. [link]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77450077/how-to-select-the-copula-function-using-the-appropriate-artificial-intelligence